Vue3. Interface import/export error after migrate to vite
I'm trying to migrate my Vue3 project from vue/cli to vite because I need to upgrade TypeScript from 4.5.5 to 5+.
After changing packages/configurations/etc and running the project I got a lot of errors:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'some_file_with_interface.ts' does not provide an export named 'default'.

For example:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/licensing-center/src/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IUtilsService.ts?t=1730135900450' does not provide an export named 'default' (at index.ts:2:8)

/app/Service/UtilsService/index.ts
import { App } from '@vue/runtime-core';
import IUtilsService from './Contract/IUtilsService';
import UtilsService from './UtilsService';

export default {
  install(app: App) {
    app.provide('utilsService', new UtilsService());
  },
};

export {
  IUtilsService,
};

/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IUtilsService.ts
import IArrayTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IArrayTool';
import IClipboardTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IClipboardTool';
import IComparatorTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IComparatorTool';
import IDataTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IDataTool';
import IDateTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IDateTool';
import IFileTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IFileTool';
import IJsonTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IJsonTool';
import IObjectTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IObjectTool';
import IStringTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IStringTool';
import IStyleTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/IStyleTool';
import ITypeCheckTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/ITypeCheckTool';
import ICheckConditionTool from '@/widgets/FormComponent/lib/Contract/ICheckConditionTool';
import INumberFormatTool from '@/app/Service/UtilsService/Contract/INumberFormatTool';

export declare interface IUtilsService {
  array: IArrayTool;
  checkCondition: ICheckConditionTool;
  clipboard: IClipboardTool;
  comparator: IComparatorTool;
  data: IDataTool;
  date: IDateTool;
  file: IFileTool;
  json: IJsonTool;
  numberFormat: INumberFormatTool;
  object: IObjectTool;
  string: IStringTool;
  style: IStyleTool;
  typeCheck: ITypeCheckTool;
}

export default IUtilsService;

tscongif.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": false,
    "preserveValueImports": false,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.json"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}

All these files worked fine while the project was building on vue/cli, but now, on vite, the pages don't load due to errors in js.
Is there a way to fix this error other than changing all interfaces (of which there are over a hundred) "import TypeName;" to "import { type TypeName }" and "export default TypeName" to "export { type TypeName };"?
